# Why can't I edit or delete a blob on Azure?

Tags: azure, blob, azure-storage, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

I've been given a website hosted by Azure.  The data for the site is stored in blobs instead of tables.  Our client wants us to edit one of those blobs.  I downloaded the blob through Visual Studio, edited it in a text editor (I've tried Notepad, Notepad++, and Wordpad), and then uploaded it through Visual Studio.  The upload seems to work, but when I view the website, the data hasn't changed.  I'm guessing that either the data isn't being uploaded correctly or that there is a cache that is restoring the original data.  Any suggestions on what's going on?

Here's something else I tried that may point to the problem.  I tried deleting the blob entirely and it reappeared after I viewed the website.

So here's the blob originally.  Note that the modified time is 7:23:15 PM. [image]

I select the blob and then click the red X.  I get a confirmation message and choose yes.

[image]

I choose yes and the blob seems to be gone.

[image]

I then go to the website and navigate to the page that uses the blob data.  The blob has reappeared!  Note the time is now 7:53:01 PM which is about the time I opened the website.

[image]

What is going on here and how can I edit a blob without my changes being overwritten?

Answer (score 0):

Any chance your site is using a CDN that reads from the blob storage? CDNs take a few hours to update their cache, which would explain the delay you're seeing

Comment: Anything is possible.  I was given the website and told the data was in blobs on Azure.  That's about all I know.  How would I know if the site is using a CDN?  I tried deleting the blob yesterday and the next morning it was back.  Plus the fact the the blob seems to be deleted and then recreated.  These two things seem to point to me that it's not just a delay.

Comment: @boilers222 do you see the deleted blob reappearing in blob storage? If so, then there's probably some automation somewhere who's job is to keep the blob in sync with some repository somewhere.  Your best bet in that case is to find the repository and make the changes there

Comment: @boilers222 It's also possible that the code to repopulate the blob is somewhere in the site itself, since the blob was modified when you loaded the site. It's best to just tell whoever pointed you to the blob storage what's going on and ask how people normally edit the site.

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at what is going on in your code? You can try to look at diagnostics logs of your Azure Storage (for example, here is the old but good article https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2011/08/02/windows-azure-storage-logging-using-logs-to-track-storage-requests/).
Anyway, i strongly suspect that it is not what platform could do. If blob appears when you access your site, then it should be a code in it. To analyse the content of the blob can be helpful as well - maybe it some kind of a session data.